# Get the state of a CSS animation in JavaScript and print it inside an element or on the console so as to later manipulate it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to replicate a marquee tag using CSS3 animation and I'd like to call a function when the state of the animation changes from running to paused or initial.

HTML:

```
<div class='animationBackground'><p id="marqueeText">Scrolling Text Goes Here</p></div>
<div id="animationState">Animation State</div>
<button id='stop' type"button" onclick=stopInterval()>Stop Logging</button>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes marquee
    {
        0%   { transform: translate(0%, 0); }
        100% { transform: translate(-200%, 0);}
    }

    p {
        margin-left: 100%;
        padding-inline-end: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 30pt;
        z-index: 10;
        animation: marquee 25s linear 0s 1
    }

    .animation{
        width: 100%;
        background-color: darkblue;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);

function myTimer() {
    var marqueeText = document.getElementById('marqueeText');
    var animationState = document.getElementById('animationState');
    animationState.innerHTML = marqueeText.style.animationPlayState;
    console.log(marqueeText.style.animationPlayState);

    if(marqueeText.style.animationPlayState == "running"){
        doSomething();
    }

}

function stopInterval(){
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

The line below doesn't yield anything:

```
animationState.innerHTML = animatedText.style.animationPlayState;
```

nor does this one. I get a blank `<div>` and the console also doesn't print anything.

```
console.log(animatedText.style.animationPlayState);
```

---

Is it possible to get any of the states so as to manipulate them using Javascript? e.g `running|paused|initial|inherit` using the doSomething() function.

Comment: This has rather little to do with animations per se, and is rather just the general “problem” that `element.style` only allows you to read styles that where _explicitly_ set before (style attribute, or JS) - but that is not the case anywhere in your code. Try getComputedStyle instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Odd, I don't know if it's a browser bug or what.. but it seems that you can not, in fact, access that property of the element, even if it's explicitly assigned in the css.

`getComputedStyle` does seem to work though.

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 2000);

var marqueeText = document.getElementById('marqueeText');
function myTimer() {
    var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(marqueeText);
    printState(computedStyle.animationPlayState);
    if(computedStyle.animationPlayState == "running"){
        //doSomething();
    }

}

function stopInterval(){
    clearInterval(myVar);
    marqueeText.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
    var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(marqueeText)
    printState(computedStyle.animationPlayState);
}

function printState(state){
  var animationState = document.getElementById('animationState');
  console.log(state);
  animationState.innerHTML = state;
}
```

```css
@keyframes marquee
    {
        0%   { transform: translate(0%, 0); }
        100% { transform: translate(-200%, 0);}
    }

    p {
      color:#000;
        margin-left: 100%;
        padding-inline-end: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 30pt;
        z-index: 10;
        animation: marquee 25s linear 0s 1;
        
    }

    .animation{
        width: 100%;
        background-color: darkblue;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
```

```html
<div class='animationBackground'><p id="marqueeText">Scrolling Text Goes Here</p></div>
<div id="animationState">Animation State</div>
<button id='stop' type"button" onclick=stopInterval()>Stop Logging</button>
```

*Insert snarky comment about marquee being deprecated for a reason here* :-p

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using Web Animation API in order to create keyframes based animations and check their status programmatically using a callback when event handler `onfinish` is being trigged.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API

in case you need to support older browsers you can use this polyfill:

https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js

or you can use the dom event

```
window.onload = function() {
  var elm = document.querySelector('.marquee'); // get dom with your animation

  elm.addEventListener('animationend', function(e) { 
    console.log('fires when animation ends');
  });
  elm.addEventListener('animationstart', function(e) { 
    console.log('fires when animation starts');
  });
}
```